# SQLite data file as graphical pie chart webpage?

Tags: python, html, pie-chart

I'm am looking for a way I could visually show data from SQLite3 data file in a webpage that would load the file every refresh, is there a way I could achieve this with Python? Django? Or JavaScript? Hope you can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Yes, using the three tools that you have listed, or others. It's not possible to give a more detailed answer because there are many ways of achieving this; it's not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow unless you have some specific issue with the code of your implementation.

Comment: Please read my comment again, I said that there was no way to answer this question and that you needed to be more specific. I did not suggest I was going to do anything. Also, responding to a comment after 6 months is not particularly helpful. If you post a question you should be ready to take comments, respond to feedback or give more feedback as quickly as possible.